# Word order: "Where are..." and "Where they..."

Tags: present-tense

In "Aliens" movie I listened phrase "Where they are?".

Is it one of American English specific word order or grammatical mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a question, it should be *Where are they?*

*Where they are* could be a relative clause, usually used as part of a sentence, but it could be separated if it appears as the answer to a question, for example:

A: *Where should I expect to find them?*
B: *Where they are!*

There might also be a use by someone who doesn't speak English natively, or a mishearing.

Answer (score 2):

I can't check the movie, but according to the original script at [this site](https://www.dailyscript.com/scripts/Aliens_James_Cameron_May_28_1985_first_draft.html), this phrase occurs in a conversation between Ripley (the main character, who survived her encounter with the Alien in the first movie) and Vasquez (a young Marine). Ripley is explaining to Vasquez and the other Marines how dangerous the Alien is.

> VASQUEZ I only need to know one thing.

> RIPLEY Yes?

> VASQUEZ Where they are.

> Vasquez coolly points her finger, cocks her thumbs, and blows away an imaginary alien.

So this is not a question; she's not asking "Where are they?". It's part of statement, basically "The only thing I need to know is where they are (and I will kill them)".

Especially when trying to understand English in movies, it is important to include the context in which words occur.

Comment: Thank you for an explanation.